# How do I print all the numbers By adding 1 with them, from a string type input?

Tags: c++

In this code, Input will be a string of integer and output will be an integer by adding 1 with those numbers. But when I executing my code I'm getting only the first number of the string.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

string M;
cin>>M;

stringstream ss(M);

int array[100];

int i=0;

  while(ss>>array[i]){
    ++i;
  }

for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
    cout<<array[j] + 1<<" ";
}

return 0;
}
```

**The sample I/O:**

```
I: 12 13 14
O: 13 14 15
I: 1 2 3 4 5
O: 2 3 4 5 6
```

**But I'm getting:**

```
I: 12 13 14
O: 13
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to read a whole line, instead of just the first number, use `getline` for that

```
string M;
getline(cin, M);

stringstream ss(M);
```

Answer (score 1):

The space limits the reading of string using cin. To get all the number in the same lines, you may use getline instead.

```
getline(cin, M);
```